# When passing data from AJAX call it returns None type

Tags: ajax, django

I want to pass data from AJAX call.Data wants to be the (form input data+key).
When i pass the data it returns the data that i want.But it also returns a None type value.
I want to get rid of that None type value.

Following shows my form template code.

```
<form action="/seq_input/" method="POST" id="MyForm"><br>
      <p style="color:black;font-size:14px">These messages haven't reciever.</p>
      <p style="color:black;font-size:14px">If you want you can add recivers</p>
      <table id="tb1">
          <tr>
              <th style="display:none;">Key</th>
              <th>Message</th>
              <th>Reciver</th>
          </tr>
             {% for key,values in NullList.items%}
            <tr>
                <td style="display:none;">{{key}}</td>
                <td>{{values}}</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="{{key}}" name={{key}} value=""></td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
       </table>
       <br>
       <input type="submit" value="SubmitMyInputs" onclick="get_details()">
  </form>
```

following shows the Ajax call.

```
    var jsonArr = [];
   function get_details(){
    console.log("submit");
    console.log(myObject);
    for(var value in myObject){
    var x=document.getElementById(myObject[value]).value;

    jsonArr.push({
    key:myObject[value],
    reciever:x
  });
 }
alert(JSON.stringify(jsonArr));
get_ajax(jsonArr);

}
function get_ajax(jsonArr){
  $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url:  $('#MyForm').attr('action'),
                data: {'data': JSON.stringify(jsonArr)},
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response)
                    alert('success');
                },
                error: function(response) {
                    console.error(response)
                    alert('error');
                }
            });

 }
```

Following has my .py file code.

```
    def get_seq_input(request): 
     if request.method == 'POST':
      message = request.POST.get('data')
      print(message)
```

the result is
    [{"key":1,"reciever":"system"}] and 
    None

anyone have idea to getrid of this None?

Comment: What do you mean "and None"? Where is this None?

Comment: When i print the message it returns  [{"key":1,"reciever":"system"}] and None. when running the get_seq_input(request) method, it runs twice and print these two result.message= [{"key":1,"reciever":"system"}] and message=None.

Comment: what's result of `JSON.stringify(jsonArr)`?

Comment: It's twice, because you're submitting the form twice. First time with onclick and second time with default submit POST. You need to update your get_details() function to prevent default form behavior.

Comment: adding prevent default is work.But now page is not ridirected to another page if i add that method.

Comment: You can redirect the page in get_ajax() function on success with window.location.replace('yourRedirectUrlHere') or window.location.href = 'yourRedirectUrlHere').

Comment: It is right.But the page that i want to pass need context.I have no idea to pass it with context with this function

Comment: @seuling   JSON.stringify(jsonArr)={"key":1,"reciever":"system"}]

Comment: There are a number of solutions, one being to save the data to session and then get it from session on redirect. But the question you need to ask yourself is if using ajax is the right approach here.

Comment: can you tell me another right approach to it?